# Iterate over a tensor dimension in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to develop a seq2seq model from a low level  perspective (creating by myself all the tensors needed). I am trying to feed the model with a sequence of vectors as a two-dimensional tensor, however, i can't iterate over one dimension of the tensor to extract vector by vector. Does anyone know what could I do to feed a batch of vectors and later get them one by one?

This is my code:

```
batch_size = 100
hidden_dim = 5
input_dim = embedding_dim
time_size = 5



input_sentence = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64, shape=[embedding_dim,None], name='input')
output_sentence = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64, shape=[embedding_dim,None], name='output')

input_array = np.asarray(input_sentence)
output_array = np.asarray(output_sentence)

gru_layer1 = GRU(input_array, input_dim, hidden_dim) #This is a class created by myself


for i in range(input_array.shape[-1]):
    word = input_array[:,i]
    previous_state = gru_encoder.h_t
    gru_layer1.forward_pass(previous_state,word)
```

And this is the error that I get

```
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got <tf.Tensor 'input_7:0' shape=(10, ?) dtype=float64>
```

Comment: Just a guess but I think tensorflow uses numpy arrays to do this sort of thing so I would check out the numpy docs.

Comment: Can you please post [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have and what you would like to obtain exactly?

Comment: I though the same, however this doesn't even work. I tried to pass the tensor through `np.asarray` before, but it daoesn recognise the tensor as an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found an approach that solves my problem. It worked using `tf.scan()` instead of a loop, which doesn't require the input tensor to have a defined number in the second dimension. Consecuently you hace to prepare the input tensor previously to be parsed as you want throught `tf.san()`. In my case this is the code:

```
batch_size = 100
hidden_dim = 5
input_dim = embedding_dim
time_size = 5



input_sentence = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64, shape=[embedding_dim,None], name='input')
output_sentence = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64, shape=[embedding_dim,None], name='output')

input_array = np.asarray(input_sentence)
output_array = np.asarray(output_sentence)

x_t = tf.transpose(input_array, [1, 0], name='x_t')

h_0 = tf.convert_to_tensor(h_0, dtype=tf.float64)
h_t_transposed = tf.scan(forward_pass, x_t, h_0, name='h_t_transposed')
h_t = tf.transpose(h_t_transposed, [1, 0], name='h_t')
```

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow does deferred execution.

You usually can't know how big the vector will be (words in a sentance, audio samples, etc...). The common thing to do is to cap it at some reasonably large value and then pad the shorter sequences with an empty token.

Once you do this you can select the data for a time slice with the slice operator:

```
data = tf.placeholder(shape=(batch_size, max_size, numer_of_inputs))
....
for i in range(max_size):
  time_data = data[:, i, :]
  DoStuff(time_data)
```

Also lookup tf.transpose for swapping batch and time indices. It can help with performance in certain cases.

Alternatively consider something like `tf.nn.static_rnn` or `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` to do the boilerplate stuff for you.

Comment: i considered the option of the max_size, however, it doesn't seem to be good performance, I expected a better alternative from tensorflow. Am i wrong?

Comment: @ÁngelDelgadoPanadero tf.nn.dynamic_rnn can stop earlier. However if you have a batch you need still need to cover the longest sequence in the batch. Works best if you make batches have similar sequence lengths. Before talking performance try out the simplest thing and see how it works. It might be that it's fast enough.

Comment: I understand your point but it is not only a matter of performance rather than I can't believe that there is no approach to iterate over a dimension of a tensor. I will make difficult  every low level programme